# Samsung s4 device override Switch selectors/style preferences

Tags: android, galaxy

I have a little trouble with Samsung S4 devices:

In one of my xml's, I use **Switch**'s gui elements with my proper customized selectors (background images with different states, pressed/not pressed ... ) and other **style**'s preferences.
Everything's works fine on all devices, except for the new Samsung S4:

The Samsung S4 device overrides my theme/selectors and shows **Switch** with default Samsung theme/selectors (by the way, they are very ugly :) ). It means that visually **Switch** looses all of my customizations.

How I can re-override Samsung's default Switch theme ? I want my manual style  back !

For this moment, I tried to extend Switch, but this did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, you can use third party implementation of **Switch** .

I used  **Switch** backport from BoD :

https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport